# matrix interesting problem about determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Hi guys i am a new member and i need help about this problem .
Let  $A=(a_{ij}) \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{Z})$ ,  $p$  a prime, and  $\tilde{A}\in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{F}_p)$  be the matrix obtained by reducing every $a_{ij}$  modulo  $p$ . If  $rank(\tilde{A})=r$ , how can I show that  $\det(A)$  is divisible by  $p^{n−r}$ ?

Comment: Smith decomposition?

Comment: hi trevor , sorry but our professor didn't teach this tecnique yet. :(

Comment: Then you should tell us what you have learnt so far. There's no point receiving an answer that you can't use yet.

Comment: sorry, you are right , that's my fault. I only learned the basic iterative formula for determinant and basic things because we have introduced determinant just few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

$\tilde{A}$ has rank $r$ if and only if there exists invertible matrices $g,h\in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that $$
g\tilde{A}h=\begin{bmatrix}
I_r & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$ where $I_r$ denotes the $r\times r$-identity matrix and $0$'s denote $0$ matrices of correct sizes. This matrix is called the Smith Normal Form of $\tilde{A}$.

Pick $G,H\in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\tilde{G}=g$ and $\tilde{H}=h$. Then, $\tilde{GAH}=g\tilde{A}h$, so each entry of $GAH$ is divisible by $p$, except the first $r$ diagonal entries. In particular, $n-r$ columns of $GAH$ is divisible by $p$ and the multilinearity of $\det$ implies that $\det(GAH)$ is divisible by $p^{n-r}$. On the other hand, $\det(GAH)=\det(G)\det(A)\det(H)$ and $\det(G),\det(H)$ are not divisible by $p$ since $g,h$ are invertible. Thus, $p^{n-r}$ divides $\det(A)$.